# syntax error at or near "RETURNING" PSQL Select with returning statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have the following query:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        profileid as id_user,
        terms_accepted as terms_accepted_passport,
        lastname as last_name_user,
        firstname as first_name_user,
        picture_serving_url as picture_user,
        is_active as status_user,
        is_passport_active as status_passport,
        language as language_id_user,
        created as created_user,
        modified as modified_user,
        passport_completion_level as completion_level_passport,
        email as email_user,
        about_me as description_user,
        uni_code as institution_id_user,
        metadata as metadata_misc
    FROM import_temp_table
    RETURNING
        id_user
)
select * FROM data
```

The output is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURNING"
LINE 19:     RETURNING
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes - returning is for insert/update - select returns rows itself - no need to use returning

Comment: What is the `returning` clause supposed to do here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @VaoTsun marking your answer as correct in 9min.

Comment: @Mureinik hey, what I want to do is use the data returned from the "variable" assigned on the top to perform 3 inserts on the same query with that data (coming from another place which is NOSQL) so that the data can be in a PSQL DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this?..

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        profileid as id_user,
        terms_accepted as terms_accepted_passport,
        lastname as last_name_user,
        firstname as first_name_user,
        picture_serving_url as picture_user,
        is_active as status_user,
        is_passport_active as status_passport,
        language as language_id_user,
        created as created_user,
        modified as modified_user,
        passport_completion_level as completion_level_passport,
        email as email_user,
        about_me as description_user,
        uni_code as institution_id_user,
        metadata as metadata_misc
    FROM import_temp_table
)
select id_user FROM data
```

and in case I guessed, this should do:

```
select profileid as id_user from import_temp_table
```

Comment: This is why people should sleep often. Thanks, this is what I need.

Comment: no worries - please read the shorter version of your query as well

Comment: hey, that was just a modifier I did to see if it works, but I need all the data as shown on my query because most of those fields are going to different tables, it happens that all this data was a giant google datastore table and is now being migrated to a PSQL DB.

Comment: ah - it makes sense why you met difficulties then. well - ignore shorter version then

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
        profileid as id_user
 FROM import_temp_table
    RETURNING id_user into id_user_